# Publishing PostGIS layer where PostgreSQL in Amazon RDS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl

I am trying to publish a PostGIS layer in GeoServer from my local machine. PostgreSQL is in AWS RDSs server. I am unable to see any features in layer preview. AWS RDS is SSL-enabled. it is worknig fine if SSL connection is disabled.

How can I fix this while SSL-enabled?

GeoServer is in my local machine and PostgreSQL in AWS RDS.

Comment: please add the relevant section of the GeoServer log file to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: Since the problem is certificate configuration, you need to specify the operating system of the GeoServer box, and how you configured the certificate. This is very nearly a PostgreSQL issue more than a GeoServer one.

Comment: @Vince i haven't done any configurations, i am actually trying to access postgis table from my local machine's geoserver and add this as a layer. local machine os is windows. i am very new to these things

Comment: Can psql connect to the RDS server?